# "Cannot set property of undefined" error in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am new to Angular, so i think i am making some silly mistake but still not being to get a hold of it. 
I have created a service to fetch some data, then i have injected the service in my controller.

Service -

```
  .service('getAllCompanies', ['$http', function ($http) {
    // AngularJS will instantiate a singleton by calling "new" on this function
    var url = "http://localhost:8000/companies/?page=";
    this.getCompanies = function(p) {
        return $http.get(url+p);
    };
  }]);
```

Controller -

```
.controller('CompaniesallCtrl', ['getAllCompanies', function (companiesService) {
    var pageNumber = 1;
    this.companiesNumber = "";
    companiesService.getCompanies(pageNumber)
        .then(function(response){
            console.log(response.data.count);
            this.companiesNumber = response.data.count;
        }, function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        })
  }]);
```

I am getting this error in the console -

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'companiesNumber' of undefined
    at companiesall.js:17
    at processQueue (angular.js:16170)
    at angular.js:16186
    at Scope.$eval (angular.js:17444)
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:17257)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:17552)
    at done (angular.js:11697)
    at completeRequest (angular.js:11903)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (angular.js:11836)
```

The console.log(response.data.count) gives the correct result, so I am confused why is it showing undefined. Please help!

Comment: var self = this;
self.compainesNumber = "";


companiesService.getCompanies(pageNumber)
        .then(function(response){
           self.companiesNumber = response.data.count;
       });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also set your controller as a variable in the scope of the function.

Something like:

```
.controller('CompaniesallCtrl', ['getAllCompanies', function (companiesService) {
    var pageNumber = 1;
    var ctrl = this;
    ctrl.companiesNumber = "";
    companiesService.getCompanies(pageNumber)
        .then(function(response){
            console.log(response.data.count);
            ctrl.companiesNumber = response.data.count;
        }, function(error) {
           console.log(error);
        }) 
}]);
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are using [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode)? Then context inside of `then` callback is going to be global object but `this` is indeed `undefined`. Use [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) that will preserve lexical scope (controller instance in this case):

```
companiesService.getCompanies(pageNumber)
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data.count);
        this.companiesNumber = response.data.count;
    }, function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    })
```

Or [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to correct context:

```
companiesService.getCompanies(pageNumber)
    .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response.data.count);
        this.companiesNumber = response.data.count;
    }.bind(this), function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    })
```